# PHP Regex Look Around Help

Tags: php, regex

Basically I have some text that looks like the following:

```
{hello|hi} this {is really|is actually} great.
```

I want to create a regex for preg_replace that will replace the word "really" except the tricky part is that I don't want the word to be within {}

I have been trying to use the regex look around feature but I just can't quite get a syntax working that will check if it's within { but not before a }.

Comment: can you have `{hello|hy|good day|goobye}` or `{{hy|hello}|{good|bad}}` in your syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
(?<!{)([^{}\r\n]*?)really(?![^{\r\n]*})
```

and replace with

```
$1Replacement
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ufmq)

**Constraints:**

- No nested brackets
- No unmatched brackets

One problem is that PHP allows only fixed length lookbehind, therefore you have to replace with `$1 + Replacement`

`(?<!{)` negative look behind assertion, no `{` on the left

`([^{}\r\n]*?)` negated character class, does not allow `{}` and line break characters (you can try without if needed) lazy matched 0 or more times, the content of this group is stored in `$1`

`(?![^{\r\n]*})` negative look ahead assertion does not allow a `}` to follow with `{` or line break character sin between.

Comment: This is what I was after! Thank you :)