# A preg_match using regexp are losing the last character

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I have a file(.txt) that I would like to have formated. the lines look like this =>

```
Name on Company
Street 7 CITY phone: 1234 - 56 78 91 Webpage: www.webpage.se
http://www.webpage.se

Name on Restaurant
Street 11 CITY CITY phone: 7023 - 51 83 83 Webpage:
http://
```

The problem I'm having is with my regexp when i would like to match the city(which is in uppercase). So far I'm come up woth this =>

```
preg_match('/\b[A-ZÅÄÖ]{2,}[ \t][A-ZÅÄÖ]+|[A-ZÅÄÖ]{2,}\b/', $info, $city);
```

As you can see it is swedish city's I'm working with thus A-ZÅÄÖ. But using this regexp doesnt work if the last character in the citys name is either 'ÅÄÖ' in these cases it just take the characters before that.

are anyone seeing the problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: If you are using multibyte characters, make sure the text of your php file with the regexp string, and the `$info` var (from your txt file) all are in UTF8, and always use the `u` flag on the regexp. This is the only way preg_match will understand Unicode characters instead of bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `\b` is defined as matching the border between characters that are in `\w` and those that are not.

Your swedish-specific characters are not in `\w` (which is typically equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`).

You can instead replace `\b` with appropriate lookaround assertions ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089491/php-regex-look-around-help)).

Comment: /[A-ZÅÄÖ]{2,}[ \t][A-ZÅÄÖ]+|[A-ZÅÄÖ]{2,}/     I did like this and it worked, not sure if this is what you meaned but thanks anyway about /b boundry, news for me.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, this would to seem be a *perfect* place to use http://txt2re.com to develop and test your regex from examples.

That being said, there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the regex that would cause it to skip trailing `ÅÄÖ` character.  Those are being treated no differently than the other alphabetic characters.

I suspect a Unicode problem.  Perhaps the input data has a trailing `Ä` that is stored as an `A` followed by a separate [diaresis combining character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a8/index.htm).  The solution for this is to [normalize the unicode string](http://php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php) prior to applying the regex.

Also, as Amber points-out, the problem may be with the `\b` definition of a word boundary.  The [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) say, `A "word" character is any letter or digit or the underscore character, that is, any character which can be part of a Perl "word". The definition of letters and digits is controlled by PCRE's character tables, and may vary if locale-specific matching is taking place. For example, in the "fr" (French) locale, some character codes greater than 128 are used for accented letters, and these are matched by \w.`  So, you may get relief by changing your locale setting.

Alternatively, you can try setting the `u` [pattern modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) in case the input is in UTF-8.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question... would probably be better as a comment.